# Prevent auto calling function in angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs and i have an issue that when i run my app, the factory function call twice time. I want to prevent by calling function from Factory function.

**Here is my code:-**

```
advisoryApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
            })
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
                controller: 'aboutController'
            })
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
                controller: 'contactController'
            });
});

advisoryApp.factory('HttpResponse', function ($http) {
    return{
        getHttpResponse: function (method, url, data) {
            return $http({
                url: url,
                method: method,
                data: data
            })
        }
});

advisoryApp.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, HttpResponse, $rootScope) {
    $scope.allAdvisoryData = '';
    var segment_id = 5;
    var url = $rootScope.base_url + "web_service/call_listing/" + segment_id;
    var data = 'segment_id=' + segment_id;

    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
    HttpResponse.getHttpResponse('POST', url, data).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**Here is my output:-**

Here api i.e `POST http://localhost/advisory_mandi/web_service/call_listing/5` call twice but i want, it should call only one time.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most common reason is that you initialise your controller twice.
Few options:

- Controller initialised from router and from html with `ng-controller`
- Application initialised twice. Maybe you call `ng-app` twice
- Application bootstrapped from javascript and also from html

Comment: yes..! the reason is that i have initialize controller twice.